# Dynamic CSS Grid for first two cells

Tags: css, css-grid

I currently have a dynamic CSS grid set up, where the first cell width is always spread across the number of columns. I would instead like it to be the first two cells are split 50/50 across the first row, with the rest being dynamic (unless there is only one column, in which case have all of the cells display like a usual column). Not sure how to achieve this.

My grid parent code:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(380px, 1fr));
}
```

And the code for the first cell in the grid:

```
.grid > :first-child {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

So ideally, having first two cells split 50/50 across the first row, then automatically fill the rest depending on the size of the screen:

[image: Image showing desired layout]

Comment: You can make use of grid-area or grid-template-areas.

Comment: is it always the same number of columns ? if, use a template of 6 columns, span the first two accross 3 and the others across 2.  If number columns may change, you will need javascript to reset spanning value for the first 2 onload and on resize events.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Yeah that is the issue, they auto-fit to the size of the screen, so there could be 1 column or 5, ideally I'd want to have some sort of ```grid-area: 50% / 1 / 1 / -1``` style code, but that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but what I ended up doing was wrapping the elements I wanted to be featured (i.e. the top two boxes in the diagram there) in a div, then styling it as follows:

```
.grid .featured {
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
}

.grid .featured>div {
    width: calc(50% - 1rem); //Only fill 50% of div, minus half of the gap defined above
}
```

I then added a couple of media queries when below a certain width, or when the grid reduces to a single column

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 963px) {
    .grid .featured {
        display: contents !important; //Not sure why contents works, but it does
    }

    .grid .featured>div {
        width: auto !important;
    }
}
```